# How do I save a MKPointAnnotation to Pars?

Tags: swift, parse-platform, mkannotation, pfobject, geopoints

How do I save on Parse a `MKPointAnnotation` that I created?

```
@IBAction func salvaRicordo(sender: AnyObject) {
    let puntoRicordo = MKPointAnnotation()
    puntoRicordo.coordinate = posizioneUtente
    puntoRicordo.title = nomeField.text
    puntoRicordo.subtitle = descrizioneField.text
    self.myMapView.addAnnotation(puntoRicordo)
    print("PointAnnotation creato")
    puntoRicordo.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if (success) {
        // The object has been saved.
    } else {
        // There was a problem, check error.description
    }
}
```

Comment: save the coordinates of parse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't save a `MKPointAnnotation` to Parse directly. You may want to save its properties such as `coordinate`, `title` and `subtitle`.

If you want to save coordinates, you should split them into latitudes and longitudes.

In Parse you can create a new class, call it "Annotations", add columns named "Title", "Subtitle", "Latitude" and "Longitude", and save your data this way:

```
let myObject = PFObject(className: "Annotations")
myObject["Title"] = nomeField.text
myObject["Subtitle"] = descrizioneField.text
myObject["Latitude"] = puntoRicordo.latitude
myObject["Longitude"] = puntoRicordo.longitude
myObject.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if (success) {
        print("Data saved to Parse.")
    } else {
        print(error)
    }
}
```